# How to capture a poping window?

Tags: windows, window, popups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Irritating pop-up flash](https://superuser.com/questions/207141/irritating-pop-up-flash)

I am running Windows 7 and some process constantly pops up a window that closes way too fast. I am not able to  understand which process does that.

I have removed several applications already incl. Antivirus but I still cannot catch what is happening.

Is there a way to catch that windows somehow to see which process causes it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> button and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste it into a new Paint page.

Comment: I am not asking about making a screenshot. I am asking about how to identify the process that quickly spawns a window and closes it. It is generally unnoticeable but it captures the focus for a moment and fullscreen applications get out of focus.